# Spring boot - Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a Springboot Application which I want to be run with embedded tomcat container.

I'm using it on a Debian System (on my Mac everything goes well).
I'm using tomcat 8.0.29. Tomcat is running correctly.
When i launch my application I got this exception. It's not the full stack trace, after this part it's all about exception in auto wiring all the possibile things..

```
2016-03-21 13:42:21.573 INFO  [main]: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
2016-03-21 13:42:24.329 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1]: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-03-21 13:42:59.223 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1]: Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
2016-03-21 13:43:03.472 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1]: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [127] milliseconds.
2016-03-21 13:43:03.593 WARN  [main]: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2016-03-21 13:43:03.838 ERROR [main]: Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at it.besmart.parkserver.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:457)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 14 more
```

Complete POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.besmart</groupId>
    <artifactId>eparkserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eparkserver</name>
    <description>ePark server</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>it.besmart.parkserver.StartServer</start-class>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>server-copy</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo message="Push to server/home/pi/park/" />
                                <scp trust="yes" todir="pi:sofia2011@192.168.3.67:/home/pi/park/">
                                    <fileset dir="${basedir}/target">
                                    </fileset>
                                </scp>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("it.besmart")
public class StartServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{


    public static void main(String[] args){


        SpringApplication.run(StartServer.class, args);


    }

     @Override
         protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
             return application.sources(StartServer.class);
     }

}
```

Which can be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm using tomcat 8.0.29. Tomcat is running correctly.`? Do you have another Tomcat running besides the embedded one you intend to use with Spring boot? In that case, you will have to change the embedded Tomcat HTTP port by adding a system property to the command line running spring boot: `-Dserver.port=XXX` as the default port (8080) is already occupied.

Comment: sorry, I mean I have tomcat 8.0.29 on my server, but it's off, it's not running

Comment: post your application starter class did you anotate this class with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: @ComponentScan("it.besmart")  delete this why did you use this

Comment: @SpringBootApplication is scan your package and beans

Comment: I put it because my StartServer class is not in the root but in a package... but anyway also putting it away did not changed the exception...

Comment: the first error I get before the exception is `Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`

Comment: Print the rest of the stack trace. You cut off the relevant part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and refactor `StartServer` and delete this `@ComponentScan("it.besmart")` because `@SpringBootApplication` also provides aliases to customize the attributes of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`

Comment: But if i exclude tomcat plugin, which will be the container? Moreover, excluding it gives me packaging error in the StartServer.class for missing ServletContext and ServletExcpetion

Comment: @besmart I edit my answer add edited dependency and bulid your project after

Comment: thank you very much @kakashi hatake, it finally works!

Comment: @besmart you are welcome,  then please confirm my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add spring-boot-starter-web dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: I added this dependency, now it looks like Tomcat starts correctly but soon after it i got `Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat`